# Return logical plan using sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparklyr

We are trying to get the **logical** plan (not to be confused with the *physical* plan) that Spark generates for a given query. According to the Spark docs [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#explain(boolean)) you should be able to retrieve this using the scala command:

```scala
df.explain(true)
```

or in sparklyr with the example code:

```r
spark_version <- "2.4.3"
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", version = spark_version)
iris_sdf <- copy_to(sc, iris)

iris_sdf %>% 
  spark_dataframe %>% 
  invoke("explain", T)
```

This command runs, but simply returns `NULL` in RStudio. My guess is that sparklyr does not retrieve content that is printed to the console. Is there a way around this or another way to retrieve the logical plan using sparklyr? The physical plan is easy to get using `dplyr::explain([your_sdf])`, but does not return the logical plan that was used to create it.

Comment: does `sdf_debug_string()` help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can get this via:

```r
iris_sdf %>% 
  spark_dataframe %>% 
  invoke("queryExecution") %>%
  invoke("toString") %>%
  cat()
```